# ng build - ./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

When I do ng build or ng serve :
This issue popped:

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I removed node_modules, package-lock.json and re-installed.
But still the same issue : unresolved